# How to delete part of string from specific word?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Below is my sql query :

```
select * from Table where col1 = @param1 and col2 = @param2
```

Now I want to **delete everything from where clause** so expected output is like below :

```
select * from Table;
```

**Code:**

```
string str = "select * from Table where col1 = @param1 and col2 = @param2";

var str = sqlQuery.Replace("where", ""); // select * from Table col1 = @param1 and col2 = @param2
```

Comment: Take a look at the methods `IndexOf` and `SubString` on a string typical homework question :S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to work with `IndexOf` and `Substring`.

```
var sql = "select* from Table where col1 = @param1 and col2 = @param2";
var index = sql.IndexOf("where", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
var newSql = sql.Substring(0, index);
```

You could use `Trim` as well to remove the white space at the end. This would look like.

```
var newSql = sql.Substring(0, index).Trim();
```

Comment: Add `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to your `IndexOf` method also.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom It should be `OrdinalIgnoreCase` since the SQL is case insensitive.

Comment: @Learning shouldn't be a problem. Just make it an extension method.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom SQL isn't always case insensitive, it depends on the colation on your databse.

Comment: @Learning Where are you struggling with the extension method?

Comment: This worked.Thank you so much for your kind help and please keep helping like this.Appreciated.I posted my answer which contains extension method.

Answer (score 1):

I created below extension method with the help of answer provided by @Mighty Badaboom.

```
 static public string Foo(this string original,string wordToFind, StringComparison stringComparision = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        {
            var index = original.IndexOf("where", stringComparision);
            return original.Substring(0, index).Trim();
        }

string newSql = Foo(str, "where", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: If you're going to create an extension method for it, although I think this is overkill for your situation, you *should* call it as one: `string newSql = str.Foo("where", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`. You don't *have* to call it like this, you can call it in the *static* way but then I don't see the point making an extension method for it.